# PDFlib first line indent

Tags: indentation, adobe-indesign, pdflib

I using PDFLib as pdf renderer and IDML format from InDesign as input format and my question: is parameter

> LeftIndent

only possible way how to create  in bullet list indent? I have found in [CookBookPdfLib](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/text-output/bulleted-list/), that PDFLib supports **LeftIndent** but no such property as in InDesign

> FirstLineIndent

I mean that if i have multiple lines with one bullet, on the first line i can apply (in InDesign), so called **FirstLineIndent**, which moves only first line of text after one bullet. 
Example of functionality: [image](http://postimg.org/image/q8oa7gomt/).

With PDFLib i have to create this functionality on my own or it is implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might check out the option "parindent". Check out the PDFlib API reference for details.

Comment: Unfortunately `parindent` doesn't take negative values - and neither does `leftindent`... So how do we create a hanging indent?

Comment: `parindent` accept negative values. Please see the following cookbook sample: http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/text-output/numbered-list/. The important part, you are always within the fitbox, which is defined by fit_textflow(). So it might be necessary to first do an indent and then use `parindent`